# How can you access a image attribute inside a div? JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hey need to solve a very quick issue. I have the following script:

```
jQuery(function($){ 
    $(window).scroll(function (){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){ 
            $('.logo-customizer').attr('src','http://13.36.14.143/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/cropped-ssssssss-1.png');
        }
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < 1000){ 
            $('.logo-customizer').attr('src','http://13.36.14.143/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/cropped-ssssssss.png');
        }
    })
});
```

And I want that when i scroll down the page, the image gets changed. For now, the image gets changed, but it gets changed on the div attribute and not the img attribute inside the div:

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class="logo-customizer" src="http://13.36.14.143/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/cropped-ssssssss-1.png"><img src="https://13.36.14.143/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/cropped-ssssssss.png" alt="Starford" width="120" height="35"></div>
```

Comment: You're selecting the class on the div but you want to change the image inside the div. Perhaps put a class or id on the thing you want to change instead of it's parent element that you don't want to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try especifing the sub-element in the selector

```
jQuery(function($){ 
    $(window).scroll(function (){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){ 
            $('.logo-customizer img').attr('src','http://13.36.14.143/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/cropped-ssssssss-1.png');
        }
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < 1000){ 
            $('.logo-customizer img').attr('src','http://13.36.14.143/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/cropped-ssssssss.png');
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <img src="https://13.36.14.143/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/cropped-ssssssss.png" class="logo-customizer" alt="Starford" width="120" height="35"/>
</div>
```

You're setting the src of your div element in your script, as you've set the class name for your div and not the img tag.

Comment: $('.logo-customizer img') could also work. But I would suggest give your img an id and then set the src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You do not select the image, you are selecting the div you need to use `$('.logo-customizer img')` instead of  `$('.logo-customizer')`.

Comment: There is no class on the `img` in the posted markup.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is @Solerman Kaplon solution but you can also use `find()` method on your `$('.logo-customizer')` object:

```js
jQuery(function($){ 
    $(window).scroll(function (){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){ 
            $('.logo-customizer').find('img').attr('src','http://13.36.14.143/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/cropped-ssssssss-1.png');
        }
        if ($(this).scrollTop() < 1000){ 
            $('.logo-customizer').find('img').attr('src','http://13.36.14.143/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/cropped-ssssssss.png');
        }
    })
});
```